# Is Shift and Scalar invariant same as independent under linear transforms?

Tags: scale-invariance, invariance

I saw "shift and scale invariant" terms for the first time, and I'm wondering what's their meaning? in other word: *Is Shift and Scalar invariant same as invariant under linear transforms?*
thanks.

Comment: Can you give us an in context quote where this is used?  A naive interpretation of a "shift invariant" function would be one satisfying $f(x + a) = f(x)$.  But then, for all $x$, $f(x) = f(0 + x) = f(0)$, giving a constant function.  The context would help resolve my confusion.

Comment: @MatthewDrury see the abstract 
[in this link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279070596_A_note_on_high-dimensional_two-sample_test)

Comment: Your title doesn't match the body -- the title has "independent" where the body text has "invariant". Please fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper you linked answers this question:

> In contrast, $T_n$ is not invariant under orthogonal transformations, but it is invariant under location shifts and scalar transformations.

Orthogonal transformations are linear, so it would seem the answer is *no*.

*Location shifts* and *scalar transformation* seem to have a domain specific definitions that I've not encountered before.  From the same paper

> Here, the location shifts and scalar transformations mean $X_{ij} \mapsto B X_{ij} + c$ for $i=1,2, \ldots$, $j=1,\ldots,n_i$, where $c$ is a constant vector, $B=\text{diag}(b_{21},...,b_{2p})$, and $b_{21}, ..., b_{2p}$ are non-zero constants.

They don't offer a definition of *constant vector*, but it seems they must mean a vector all of who's components are equal.  You'd have to read in detail to be sure.  As for *scalar transformation*, generally I'd expect all the diagonal entries to be equal for that.  Quite confusing use of terminology here.

Comment: Yes! Unfortunately the terminology is quite confusing. need to read more and simulate it models to become sure! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According the the terminology in the paper, the scalar transformations (from Proposition 1) only allow full rank diagonal matrix products. Hence, as the multiplication by $0$ is a linear operation, you have your counter-example.

Following a constructive exchange with @Matthew Drury, I have found the paper [Finite Groups Represented by Special Matrices](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1989006), G. A. Miller, Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, 1916, which defines:

> A square matrix in which each of the elements, with a possible exception of those of the principal diagonal, is equal to zero is called a quasi-scalar matrix

The transformations in the paper are abusively called linear. A better naming could be: "positive quasi-scalar" for the matrix part.

Comment: Is this a standard definition of *scalar transformations*?

Comment: The scalar transformations defined in the paper Proposition 1. I feel I have not been clear enough

Comment: I have read somewhere that diagonal matrices with non-zero elements can be called "quasi-scalar" (and non degenerate). I believe the term scalar here is abusive

Comment: Agreed.  This paper is abusing terminology pretty harshly.

Comment: (+1) I edited you answer for a small bit of clarity.

Comment: You did well. I have added a possibly clearer name for the transforms, and found a precise reference.

Comment: Thanks, Your example make my mind clear! Sorry that I have no enough rep to give you +1 :)

Comment: The  comment suffices